# Secure WebSocket connection closing unexpectedly - how do I reinstate connection

Tags: javascript, json, websocket

We are currently writing a web application that communicates using JSON with an Event driven Engine Server side over Secure WebSockets. 
The application seems to be fine unless you experience any TCP packet loss. Once you lose a couple of TCP packets the Web Socket connection will close with an error 1006 ( aborted connection ) 
I am looking for advice as to the best way to reestablish the WSS connection and better understand why a few lost TCP packets is causing the WSS connection to abort as I can't find any guidance on the matter.

All communication through Sockets is set out in the function below;

```
function socketHandling(address) {
    "use strict";
    var webSocketHost = URIParse(address);
    engineAddress = webSocketHost;
    if (LocalTest) {
        webSocketHost = 'ws://127.0.0.1:8123';
    }
    socket = new WebSocket(webSocketHost);
    webSocketHost = webSocketHost.split('://')[1];
    host = webSocketHost.split(':')[0];
    port = webSocketHost.split(':')[1].replace('/socketserver','');
    socket.onopen = function (e) {
        connectionLive = true;
        keepAlive();
        keepAliveStopped = false;
        $('#serverInfo').text('Connected');
        $('#connectionInfo').attr('title', "Connected to " + host + ' on port ' + port + ".");
        $('#connectionLight').removeClass('disconnected').addClass('connected');
    };
    socket.onclose = function (e) {
        serverComms("end", e.code, "", "");
        if (connectionLive) {
            socketReconnect();
        }
        connectionLive = false;
        $('#serverInfo').text('Not connected');
        $('#connectionInfo').attr('title', "Not connected to " + host + ' on port ' + port + ".");
        $('#connectionLight').removeClass('connected').addClass('disconnected');

    };

    socket.onmessage = function (e) {
        serverComms(direction = "inbound", message = e.data, rid = "", type = "");
    };
    serverComms(direction = "start");
}
```